# TuneFilterDecimate SRI mode and usage

Tags: redhawksdr

I'm gonna use the TuneFilterDecimate of Redhawk 1.10 to isolate the RDS data stream of WBFM transmissions.
I wonder why it transforms a real stream of data in a complex one when it is not required from the elaboration and if it is possible to exploit it to make a frequency shift of the signal from 57kHz to the baseband.
I followed this youtube video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wN9p8EjiQs4 to try to build a Fm waveform receiver to hear the audio stream but I heard only a distorted audio voice. Can you suggest me some settings?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

At present, TuneFilterDecimate will only output complex. You may want to use the FastFilter component instead to perform your filtering. For an example of REDHAWK doing a WBFM RDS demod, check out the Sub100 dollar project.

The documentation is here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/redhawksdr/files/redhawk-doc/1.10.0/

The Waveform used is here: https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/RBDS_wf

You'll need to install the components used within the waveform, those are located in the git repositories.